# Can I validate input with dynamically assigned min attribute in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've got two input fields of type number. I want second to have minimum attribute dependant on first field. I can dynamically change the attribute, but ng-valid does not change, when value is lower than minimum.

jsfiddle code example: http://jsfiddle.net/NBhn4/87/

Is that a bug or am I doing something wrong?
I found this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2404. It seems to suggest, that the problem was fixed. In my jsfiddle example I am using angular 1.3.5 and it's still not working.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="max" min={{min}} name='max'>
```

Using this, changes the minimum, but ng-valid seems not be be triggered after change.

Comment: It works on mine, [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/2CNz8v1Ix1giKU6ch6az?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its your angularjs version problem I hope. Use latest versions of angularjs and this code is working.

```
<form name="form" novalidate ng-init="min=1;number=0">
  Number:
  <input type="number" ng-model="number" name="number" min="{{min}}">
  <div style="color: red" ng-show="form.number.$error.min">Number must be at least {{min}}</div><br>

  Minimum:
  <input type="number" ng-model="min" name="min">

</form>
```

Comment: Forgot to mark it correct - It was in fact angular bug. It's ok after upgrade to newer version.